# Sending email out at a specific time

Tags: email, postfix, sendmail, delay

I'd like to write emails now and have them go out at some specific time in the future, eg. when the office opens in the morning.

What would be a good way to do that ?

Most user agents don't support this feature. That makes sense to me, because you probably can't expect them to run around the clock.

Is there a server side feature for delayed sendinmg ? I run a Postfix mail server right now.

What is the Unix way of doing this ?

(I know KMail has this feature, but I'd like to avoid this particular application, because it drags along a huge amount of infrastructure.)

Comment: use a `cron` job

Comment: Thats probably a good option to do it once, but not really handy to use on a regular basis...

Comment: Why? `cron` is specifically designed for doing things regularly.

Comment: I think its inconvenient, because I'll have to create files wil the email text and add cron entries manually with the appropriate "mail recpt@example.com -r myemail@foo.com < mail12345.txt" command. Thats quite a step down from regular GUI user agents.

Comment: Depends. You can as well check where your e-mail client saves drafts and then use this file in the `cron` job. E.g. for my `icedove` (essentially  `thunderbird`), it is saved in `./icedove/<profileID>/Mail/<addressID>/Drafts`. You will then just have to evaluate this file with a script to export the essentials and pass them to `mail`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using postfix, there is a mechanism explained [here](https://wiki.deimos.fr/Postfix:_hold_outgoing_mail_transport), which I
havent tried.

Reconfigure postfix by copying `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and adding lines:

```
defer_transports = hold
default_transport = hold
```

Beware, you may already have a `default_transport`. Swap your new file with the real `main.cf` and
restart postfix and send your mails.  They will be placed in the `hold` queue.
To release the queue, restore the real `main.cf`, restart postfix and force the queue to release with

```
sudo service postfix restart
sudo mailq -q
```

---

Instead of the above, you can **hold mail with a given header**, for example
if your mail program lets you add `X-` style headers, or if you want to match
on a given `Subject: junk of the day` header string.
Check that your postfix implements the `regexp` feature:

```
postconf -m|egrep 'regexp|pcre'
```

should output at least regexp. Create the file `/etc/postfix/header_checks` and place in it the
regexp pattern of the header you want to match, followed by `HOLD`, eg:

```
/Subject: *junk of the day/ HOLD
```

Add the name of this map file to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

and restart postfix. Send a suitable mail and check with `mailq`
that it is in the hold queue (a `!` shows next to the queue id.
To release and send all held mails:

```
sudo postsuper -H  ALL
sendmail -q
```

Comment: If I understand the feature correctly, it think it would hold all outgoung mails until disabled again, not individual mails.

Comment: I added an answer which matches a subject header, for example.